# Do cloud functions require a shebang?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, shebang

Code language is specified during cloud function deployment:

`gcloud functions deploy somefunc --runtime=python37 ...`

Is a shebang still required in all related files?

Eg. `#!/usr/bin/python`

How might a cloud function fail without the inclusion of this line?

Comment: no, they don't.

Comment: Where do you want to add it? in all Python file? or in your script file for deployment?

Answer (score 1):

No, they do not require a shebang. This is one of the ideas of this product. It is a Google managed serverless environment and you should not worry about things like that.

You can read more about Cloud Functions [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview).